# GridGain open source datacenter topology specification

Tags: gridgain

## GRIDGAIN DATA-CENTER REPLICATION

A few specific questions regarding the recently open-sourced Gridgain code. The gridgain.org support link says datacenter replication is not enabled for the open-source version. Is this true or false.

More imporatantly, assuming the open-source version has the datacenter feature enabled, how do we go about specifying the topology and activating the replication.

For example, the official documentation suggest to create/set a GridDrSenderCacheConfiguration, GridDrSenderHubConfiguration with details of the topology. I did this but it didnt seem to enable any cross data center replication.

More specifically, I did the following:

1. assign a dataCenterId byte parameter in the config.xml for gridgain.

       
       
       
       
       
      ...
2. define those nodes that are part of that datacenter under the 


   ... add ip addresses of nodes
3. Define above for each node in each datacenterl appropriately. In the gridgain java client code, initiate a gridgain instance and set the GridDrSenderCacheConfiguration,GridDrSenderHubConnection (along wtih the GridDrSenderHubConnectionConfiguration) as specified in the docs for each node in each datacenter and also using a dummy GridDrReceiverHubConfiguration object (all defaults)

However this does not seem to do any replication across the data centers.
Would someone from the GridGain team please give some examples of setting up the data center replication, How to setup the config.xml, and enable in the java code when instantiating a gridgain instance.

Also, I am trying to avoid intra-datacenter replication by setting the gridDrSenderHubConnectionConfiguration.setIgnoredDataCenterIds(localDC); paramter to avoid replicating if the datacenter is

Comment: Datacenter Replication is enterprise version feature. You can download enterprise version and try it. When referring to official documentation, do you mean this one: http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/Data+Center+Replication ?

Answer (score 0):

Just confirmed. Since data center replication is not present in open source version, no replication would happen in this case. Please download eval version of GridGain enterprise edition and try it out.